# Prove $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} ^{+}$ we have $e^{x}\geq \dfrac {x^{n+1}} {\left( n+1\right) !}$.

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Prove the following statement:

> $$\forall x\in \mathbb{R} ^{+}\,:\,\, e^{x}\geq \dfrac {x^{n+1}} {\left( n+1\right) !}$$

Comment: Sorry that was a previous question.

Comment: I'll edit . It's done !

Comment: Think about the exponential series.

Comment: What if $n$ is odd?

Comment: Is this supposed to be proven for all $n\in \Bbb Z^+$?

Comment: Yes that's it .

Comment: Don't you want $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ in stead of $\mathbb{R}^{*}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^x>e^x-1 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$
This series contains $\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and each term is positive. The OP's claim follows by taking only one term in this series, which is trivially less than all of them added together.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Taylor series: $$ e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac {x^{n}} {\left( n\right) !}.$$

And show that $e^x$ must necessarily be greater than or equal to any finite approximation in this manner.

Comment: This does not prove the statement at all.  When $x<0$ some of the remaining terms are negative and some are positive, so you can't say anything about the inequality.

Comment: $e^x$ is always positive, and if $x<0$ with $n$ odd then the inequality is trivially true.

Comment: Yes, that is the statement needed to complete the proof.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have prefaced this with "hint" or something.

Comment: @MarkFischler Read the question carefully. It's only referring to $x\geq0$.